# Serial Connection - 3.3v to 5V MCU's

Tags: serial

After asking [How to connect Arduino & ESP8266](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/83585/serial-communication-between-esp8266-and-arduino-sofware-and-hardware/83588#83588), I tried to build such circuit.

First I tried the code one 2 Nano's - to verify 2 MCU sending and receiving messages. After that, I started to build the following circuit:

**Take1:** MCU A: Arduino Micro 5V, MCU B: WEMOS mini. `R1`=10K, `R2`=20K. **FAIL**

**Take2:** MCU A: Arduino Micro 5V, MCU B: WEMOS mini. `R1`=1K, `R2`=2K. **FAIL**

**Take3:** MCU A: Arduino NANO ,MCU B: WEMOS mini. `R1`=1K, `R2`=2K. **FAIL**

**Take4:** MCU A: Arduino NANO 5V, MCU B: WEMOS mini. `Tx` to `Rx` (no vdiv ). **OK**

[image: Updated diagram]

**Edit1:** LCD display is connected to MCU B ( as it was tested using 2 Nano ) via I2C. Messages received are sent to LCD. PLEASE IGNORE LCD shown in not I2C

**Edit2**:

1. Diagram updated - GND was missing and POWER IN clarification.
2. LCD display is an I2C one. It shows properly WEMOS is booting up properly ( shows a boot msg ), and spits every incoming `Serial` message from other MCU. When TAKE4 and TAKE1 were taken, setup and code worked PROPERLY.

What is done wrong?

Comment: why do you say there is something wrong? ... what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @jsotola just added "EDIT1" in my question.

Comment: @jsotola sorry. added. Library does not include I2C LCD display.

Comment: In your wiring diagram you are missing the ground connection to the Wemos. Also you have the 5V pin of the Wemos connected to Vin on the Nano, I guess to provide the Nano with power. Thats incorrect. 5V needs to go to the 5V pin. Vin is connected to the internal voltage regulator, which needs at least 6V to power the Nano.

Comment: Your frizzy thing does not help much, a schematic is better. Use a level converter, doing the resistor trick is playing with the margins of the devices and is not reliable. They give voltage ratings and threshold levels for a reason and it is good to stay away from the margins, the closer you get the more susceptible to noise you are.

Comment: How is the whole thing being powered?

Comment: You can use a mosfet to convert 5v<->3.3v: https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/mosfet-voltage-level-converter. In this way you're not relying on the resistors and playing with the input margins

Comment: @lurker via nano’s usb

Comment: If it's all powered by the nano's USB, why is only the vin connected on the nano and not the 3.3v to the power rail?

Comment: @lurker what do you mean ? Vin is 5v

Comment: You say that nano is *supplying* the power to your system. Vin is a voltage *input*.

Comment: I'd the nano is supplying power, wouldn't you want the nano's 3.3v output available to the esp8266?

Comment: @lurker `Vin` also outputs 5v. So it is the same

Comment: @lurker it is not about powering the MCUs but the differnt vlogic affecting Serial communication.

Comment: @Guy.D Can you address the lack of a GND connection on the Wemos? Is that just a frizzy error or have you really missed it out?

Comment: @Majenko yes, it is an error. I'll update the diagram

Comment: Vin is NOT the same as 5V. You might measure 5V there (don't know, what the voltage regulator has on the input side, when its not used), but it is not for providing power. You are really risking to kill the voltage regulator on the Nano. Again: Do not use Vin as 5V power source. Use either the 5V pin or provide the Wemos directly with 3.3V through the 3.3V pin (though I'm not sure, if the 3.3V voltage regulator is really able to provide the necessary current for an ESP board)

Comment: RX/TX on Micro is Serial1

Comment: It's a system and the system starts with proper power and grounding. I thought it was a simple question. Your answer doesn't align well with your picture.

Comment: @lurker See edit 2 please.

Comment: @Majenko please see edit 2.

Comment: @Juraj what do you mean ? `Serial.begin(115200)` worked as expected, and show output on serial monitor as expected.

Comment: Yeah that's what you said: you're powering the system through thenano USB port. Bit you still didn't address the question of how you're then getting power from the nano to the esp8266, assuming you answered my original question about how the system is lowered completely. If the esp8266 is getting power from somewhere else, then please indicate. Yes, that can matter.

Comment: @lurker thank you for your replies! WEMOS us powered from Nano as you can see ( or I'm missing something here... )

Comment: As @chrisl has already said, Vin is not intended to be used for providing power. The documentation says that it's intended for supplying power TO the Arduino from an external supply.

Comment: @lurker OK, so to `RAW` ? still this is not the problem,since MCU is powered up ( WEMOS & LCD )

Comment: If you don't have proper power, it can be the source of various problems.

Comment: You seem to be mixing Nano and Micro boards in your setup. You do know, don't you, that the Micro has a 32U4, so `Serial` is the USB but *not* the TX/RX pins - you need `Serial1` for those. Also the TX/RX pins on the nano are connected to the FT232 chip, which will most likely interfere with your voltage divider.

Comment: @Majenko I know 32U4 have Serial comm on that chip and it behaves differently in some manner than 328P. But to get serial connection via `Tx` and `Rx` pins should I use `Serial1` ? is that what you've ment ?. 

And what is the reason for Nano's not to work with voltage divider ?

Comment: @Juraj Nano. Typo

Comment: Guy.D, yes use Serial1 for communication with esp8266 on RX/TX of the Micro

Comment: I would not power the WEMOS from the nano. They are two different microcontroller dev boards and should be each powered off of the same power source. For development, I would use a breadboard power supply that provides 3.3v and 5v. You can put 3.3v on one of the breadboard red power rails, and 5v on the other red power rail (which are designated RED by convention, and BLACK is for ground, which I see you have mixed up in your diagram). This is my advice. I realize you believe this has nothing to do with your problem and will likely ignore it. I wish you luck in solving your problem.

Comment: @lurker, Wemos D1 mini is ok with powering over 5 V pin

Comment: @lurker Although breadboard is shown in my diagram/ circuit, but this setup will be used as standalone device powered one power source (HiLink 220AC to 5V )

Comment: @Juraj Thanks. So a single 5v source would be fine. Also, I was more concerned about current than voltage although I didn't check the mini specs for max current draw.